# Runnable to be run every second only runs once in Fragment onCreateView()

Tags: android, fragment, runnable

I'm trying to update the time in a `TextView` with a `Runnable` supposed to be run every second.
The `Runnable` is started from a `Fragment`'s `onCreateView()`, but it's only executed once.

Anybody can help?

Thanks

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {

    Calendar mCalendar;

    private Runnable mTicker;
    private Handler mHandler;

    TextView mClock;

    String mFormat;

    private boolean mClockStopped = false;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        RelativeLayout view = (RelativeLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.meteo_widget, container, false);

        /*
         * Clock (from DigitalClock widget source)
         */

        mClock = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.clock);

        mCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();

        mHandler = new Handler();

        mTicker = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                if(mClockStopped) return;
                mCalendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
                mClock.setText(DateFormat.format("hh:mm:ss", mCalendar));
                mClock.invalidate();
                long now = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
                long next = now + (1000 - now % 1000);
                mHandler.postAtTime(mTicker, next);
            }
        };
        mTicker.run();

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume()
    {
        super.onResume();
        mClockStopped = true; 
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause()
    {
        mClockStopped = false;        
        super.onPause();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you stop the clock by setting  mClockStopped = true;  in onResume()

Answer (score 0):

Remove this `mTicker.run();` and create [Timer](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html) then use this method to call your [TimerTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/TimerTask.html), instead of Runnable, each one second (1000 ms) [scheduleAtFixedRate](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html#scheduleAtFixedRate%28java.util.TimerTask,%20long,%20long%29)

Comment: TimerTask is not recommended: http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/timed-ui-updates.html

Comment: Then why not to use `postDelayed(java.lang.Runnable, long)` instead of `mHandler.postAtTime(mTicker, next);` and use 1000 ms?

Comment: Because I want to "request a tick on the next hard-second boundary", like the DigitalClock widget (http://grepcode.com/file_/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.3_r1/android/widget/DigitalClock.java/?v=source).

Comment: Did you check mClockStopped? Because if it one time true, then your 'timer' will stop.

Comment: Sorry, you were right. I set a breakpoint at `if(mClockStopped) return;` but it never stopped, so I thought it was ok...

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing your times... the Handler.postAtTime takes milliseconds since boot (uptime milliseconds), while you are providing a Unix timestamp (milliseconds since January 1, 1970 00:00:00 UTC).

Comment: `long now = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();`, so it looks all right.